# How to get the row index in QtableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, pyside6

I have a qtablewidget with mysql table, and in the last column one button that i want to click to get the row index. Can i get the row index and id of the table from the qtablewidget?

```
    def datails(self):

    try:
        con=mysql.connector.connect(host='192.168.56.1', user='root', password='', database='valparaiso')

        consulta_sql = f"""SELECT a.id_apto,m.nome_morador,m.celular_morador,m.email_morador,m.rg_morador,m.tipo,a.apartamento,a.torre FROM Moradores AS m JOIN aptos AS a ON m.apto_morador=a.id_apto WHERE stats=1 AND m.id_morador = {_id}"""
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(consulta_sql)
        rows=cur.fetchall()
        print(rows)
    
        self.ui.ui_pages.Tabela.setRowCount(cur.rowcount)
        tablerow=0
        for row in rows:
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,0,QTableWidgetItem(row[1]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,1,QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,2,QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,3,QTableWidgetItem(row[4]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,4,QTableWidgetItem(row[5]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,5,QTableWidgetItem(row[6]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setItem(tablerow,6,QTableWidgetItem(row[7]))
            self.ui.ui_pages.table.setCellWidget(tablerow,7,self.build_btn())

            tablerow +=1

    except:
        print("erro", error)
    finally:
        if(con.is_connected()):
            con.close()
            cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

With the function

```py
self.ui.ui_pages.table.currentRow()
```

you should get the row of the selected item.
More details in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html?highlight=qtablewidget#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableWidget).